# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data

I am using `Neo4j Community Edition` for my application that uses `Spring Boot`.

My `Neo4j` context looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = { "com.lapots.tree.model.repository" })
public class Neo4jPersistenceContext {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("com.lapots.tree.model.domain.graph");
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }
}
```

And `repository` looks like this

```
@Repository
public interface IDialogLineRepository extends Neo4jRepository<DialogLine, String> {

    Collection<DialogLine> findByOwner(String owner);
}
```

I set couple of properties for the application

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://127.0.0.1:7687
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=admin
```

During the startup the application fails with

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dialogLineService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyExceptio
n: Error creating bean with name 'IDialogLineRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSession' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.d
ata.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defi
ned in class path resource [com/lapots/tree/model/repository/context/Neo4jPersistenceContext.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.ses
sion.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:574) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:806) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:349) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.lapots.tree.model.web.TreeModelSystemApplication.main(TreeModelSystemApplication.java:17) [main/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'IDialogLineRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSession' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.B
eanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/lapots/tree/model/repository/context/Neo4jPersistenceContext.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.
beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.dri
ver.EmbeddedDriver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:652) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:574) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested e
xception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/lapots/tree/model/repository/context/Neo4jPersistenceContext.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method fa
iled; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoun
dException: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:633) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:447) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:644) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/lapots/tree/model/repository/context/Neo4jPersistenceContext.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method fai
led; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFound
Exception: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:598) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org
.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver
        at org.neo4j.ogm.driver.DriverManager.register(DriverManager.java:24) ~[neo4j-ogm-api-3.0.0-M01.jar:na]
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.<init>(SessionFactory.java:74) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.0.0-M01.jar:na]
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.<init>(SessionFactory.java:52) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.0.0-M01.jar:na]
        at com.lapots.tree.model.repository.context.Neo4jPersistenceContext.sessionFactory(Neo4jPersistenceContext.java:17) ~[main/:na]
        at com.lapots.tree.model.repository.context.Neo4jPersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$397cc60b.CGLIB$sessionFactory$1(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at com.lapots.tree.model.repository.context.Neo4jPersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$397cc60b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1006188e.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        at com.lapots.tree.model.repository.context.Neo4jPersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$397cc60b.sessionFactory(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
        ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.neo4j.ogm.driver.DriverManager.register(DriverManager.java:21) ~[neo4j-ogm-api-3.0.0-M01.jar:na]
        ... 75 common frames omitted
```

My `build.gradle` looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

mainClassName='com.lapots.tree.model.web.TreeModelSystemApplication'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j')
    compile('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core')

    runtime('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')

    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitJupiterEngineVersion")
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitJupiterApiVersion")
}
```

Specifically I have this dependencies for `Neo4j`

```
compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j')
compile('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core')
runtime('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver')
```

Additionally I set the property `spring.data.neo4j.embedded.enabled=false` to prevent using embedded database. However it seems it still requires driver for embedded driver. Why is that?

Comment: Your startup stack trace is incomplete.  According to https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/neo4j/ogm/driver/DriverManager.java#L21 DriverManager gets a class passed in.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen added complete but there is nothing remarkable in its other parts - it simply unable to find `EmbeddedDriver` for who knows reasons...

Comment: But there is enough information to consult the sources and see that in https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/neo4j/ogm/session/SessionFactory.java#L52 the driver class name is found in the result of `new Configuration.Builder().build()`.  I would suggest tracing what this code does.

Comment: Can you run in debug mode to check why the auto-configuration thought it was a good idea to use the embedded driver?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll it seems there `        this(new Configuration.Builder().build(), packages);` and then into `new Configuration(this)` it passes `null` so it uses default driver name aka `embeddedDriver`

Comment: @StephaneNicoll it seems it does not read `properties` file

Comment: yeah well, where is that file defined? What is its name? Check the files we load by default in the doc. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accoroding to the document `SessionFactory` uses `embeddedDriver` by default when configuration is not provided.

So I just provided the configuration and it did the trick

```
@Value("${spring.data.neo4j.uri}")
private String databaseUrl;

@Value("${spring.data.neo4j.username}")
private String userName;

@Value("${spring.data.neo4j.password}")
private String password;

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder()
            .uri(databaseUrl)
            .credentials(userName, password)
            .build();
    return new SessionFactory(configuration, "com.lapots.tree.model.domain.graph");
}
```